# When variable value have space between word, doesnt show any result in WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I created a widget, that return sthe post has the same tag enter in `inputbox`.

I use WP_Query, but I have a problem.  When I enter words with space in `inputbox`, it does not return any result.  But when I enter a word without have a space, its work correctly

This is my inputbox:

```
<input type="text" 
    class="widefat" 
    id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('tagCategory')) ?>"
    name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('tagCategory')) ?>"
    value="<?php if (isset($tagCategory)) echo esc_attr($tagCategory); ?>"/>
</p>
```

This is my Query:

```
public function widget($args, $instance)
{
    extract($args);
    extract($instance);
    if (!isset($title)) $title = '';
    if (!isset($numberOfPosts)) $numberOfPosts = 5;
    if (!isset($tagCategory)) $tagCategory = '';
    if (!isset($postIconClass)) $postIconClass = '';

    $wpbp = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tag'       => $tagCategory,
        'posts_per_page' => $numberOfPosts,
        'orderby'   => 'id',
        'order'     => 'ASC'
      )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass your multi value in array, example

```
'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'some_key',
        'value'   => array(
           "value1 with space",
           "value2",
           "value3",
        ),
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
```